# Proper use of decorators

Tags: python, python-decorators

I have just started to use decorators in Python and I'm not sure to understand how to correctly use it.

Let's say I have this code :

```
def viable_decorator(fonction_viable):
    def viable(sequences, pos):
        codons = [seq[pos:pos+3] for seq in sequences]
        return not any("-" in codon for codon in codons)
    return viable

@viable_decorator
def viable(sequences, pos):
    codons = [seq[pos:pos+3] for seq in sequences]
    return not all("-" in codon for codon in codons)

sequncess = ["---aaacacaacaacaaat",
             "------aaacacacac---",
             "aaggcggaggcgg---ggg",]

print viable(sequences, 0)
```

My objective is to be able to use alternatively the two versions of the function `viable()`, according to the situation. Is this how decorators are supposed to work ? And if yes, how do I determine the choice of the `viable()` function ? Because for now, in this code, the decorator is always called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean ? (It's juste a quick code I wrote to practice, nothing really relevant)

Comment: `viable_decorator` decorator looks redundant here (it does not change the crucial function much) as the only difference is call `all()` or `any()` which can be achieved with additional argument.

Comment: oh that, yes. Just as I said, it's only a simple thing I wrote to practice and find out how decorators work :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this how decorators are supposed to work ?

No. Normally *decorators* are supposed to "decorate" the original function, or to add some additional stuff to the original one. *Not* to create a new one having no relation to the decorated one.

In your particular case:

```
def viable_decorator(fonction_viable):
    def viable(sequences, pos):
        codons = [seq[pos:pos+3] for seq in sequences]
        return not any("-" in codon for codon in codons)
    return viable
```

The decorator even doesn't use the decorated function `fonction_viable`. Of course it is syntactically valid to do so, but it's not what decorator, as the name suggested, supposed to do.

Comment: Got it. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In Python3, you can use `functools.wraps` to create a wrapped and unwrapped version of `viable`:

```
import functools
def viable_decorator(fonction_viable):
  @functools.wraps(fonction_viable)
  def viable(sequences, pos):
    codons = [seq[pos:pos+3] for seq in sequences]
    return not any("-" in codon for codon in codons)
  return viable

@viable_decorator
def viable(sequences, pos):
   codons = [seq[pos:pos+3] for seq in sequences]
   return not all("-" in codon for codon in codons)

unwrapped_viable = viable.__wrapped__
```

In this example, calling `viable` will in turn trigger `viable_decorator`. However, calling `unwrapped_viable` will call `viable` without triggering `viable_decorator`.

Comment: Sorry, the code throws an error : AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__wrapped__' What am I missing ?

Comment: @Micawber It's because you're using python 2.

Comment: @Micawber `__wrapped__` is only an attribute in Python3.

Comment: That explains a lot^^. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Decorators really are functions that take of other functions as parameters to add functionality to it. Your doesn't use "fonction_viable" anywhere, this is similar to just making a function call.

Try to think about decorators as higher order entities that will ADD something to function they are decorating.